# Insert ListView between two buttons in Android XML

Tags: android, xml, button, android-listview

I have a concept xml as shown below, how to insert listview in between two buttons?
[image]

This my xml code, What should I add or change in its code?

### main.xlm

```
<!--  main.xml -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"    
    tools:context=".Main" >
    <Button android:text="Back To Main Menu"
        android:id="@+id/btn_add_contact"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_contact_list" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/btn_add_contact"/>

    <Button android:text="Add New Moment"
        android:id="@+id/btn_add_contact"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code for that

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Main" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_add_contact"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add New Moment" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_contact_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_add_contact"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Back To Main Menu" />
```